# How to properly construct Akka Graph

Tags: java, scala, graph, akka, akka-stream

I want to create a graph that has a source and that source is linked to a broadcast which fanout through two flows and then the output is zipped to a sink.

I did almost everything, but I have two problems:

- The builder is not accepting my FanIn shape
- I am providing a sink but it is required a shape sink and I don't know how to get that

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("test");
      ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

      Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.range(1, 100);
      Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow1 = Flow.of(Integer.class).map(i -> i + 1);
      Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow2 = Flow.of(Integer.class).map(i -> i * 2);
      Sink<List<Integer>, CompletionStage<Integer>> sink = Sink.fold(0, ((arg1, arg2) -> {
          int value = arg1.intValue();
          for (Integer i : arg2) {
              value += i.intValue();
          }
          return value;
      }));
      RunnableGraph<Integer> graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(
              (builder) -> {
                  UniformFanOutShape fanOutShape = builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
                  UniformFanInShape fanInShape = builder.add(Zip.create());
                  return builder.from(builder.add(source))
                          .viaFanOut(fanOutShape)
                          .via(builder.add(flow1))
                          .via(builder.add(flow2))
                          .viaFanIn(fanInShape)
                          .to(sink);
              }
      ));
  }
  ```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to map the out ports from broadcast to the specific sub flows (flow1 and flow2) and similarly you need to map the specific flows (flow1 and flow2) coming together in zip stage to the specific port of a zip stage.

Also i think it is not clear what is expected from the flow you are writing. zip stage will return you a tuple (int, int), so output of zip in the stream would lead to stream of tuples. But your sink which is supposed to be added after zip does not accept a stream of tuples but stream of Integers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("test");
    ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.range(1, 100);
    Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow1 = Flow.of(Integer.class).map(i -> i + 1);
    Flow<Integer, Integer, NotUsed> flow2 = Flow.of(Integer.class).map(i -> i * 2);
    //create a new zip stage which accepts
    //Zip<?, ?, ?> zip1 = 
        final FanInShape2<Integer, Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> zip = builder.add(Zip.create());
    Sink<List<Integer>, CompletionStage<Integer>> sink = Sink.fold(0, ((arg1, arg2) -> {
        int value = arg1.intValue();
        for (Integer i : arg2) {
            value += i.intValue();
        }
        return value;
    }));
    RunnableGraph<Integer> graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(flow1, flow2, sink,
            (builder, flow1, flow2, sink) -> {
                UniformFanOutShape fanOutShape = builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
                UniformFanInShape fanInShape = builder.add(Zip.create());
                builder.from(builder.add(source))
                        .viaFanOut(fanOutShape)
                builder
                   .from(broadcast.out(0))
                   .via(builder.add(flow1))
                   .toInlet(zip.in0());
                builder
                   .from(broadcast.out(1))
                   .via(builder.add(flow2))
                   .toInlet(zip.in1());
               builder
                  .from(zip.out()).toInlet(sink)

            }
    ));
}
```

You can check the below link for more examples.
https://github.com/Cs4r/akka-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/cs4r/labs/akka/examples/ConstructingGraphs.java